# Adding to a class of lists

Tags: python

Programming is not my strongest suit and though the due date for this assignment was not met, I want to at least learn how this works before retaking the course for next year.

The whole point of the program is to be a shipyard management system that handles new packages that are arranged in containers which cannot go over 2000 lbs else it creates a new container for the same destination.

EDIT 3: This is the updated code. Sorry for not clarifying!! :<

```
class Shipyard:
    def __init__(self):
        self._cont = self.Container(None, None, None, None) 
        self._size = 0

    def __len__(self):
        return self._size

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self._size == 0

    def add_pack(self, owner, dest, weight):
        # adds package when container check is done

        # If shipyard is empty or container name is alphabetically lower than
        # the first container by destination name.

        if self.isEmpty() or dest < self._cont._first._dest:
            self._size += 1
            self._cont._first = self.Container(owner, dest, \
                                               weight, self._cont._first)
            self._cont._first.add_pack(owner, dest, weight)

            return  

        # Else will go through the contents of the linkedlist to find the spot
        # it belongs to.

        cur_Cont = self._cont._first


        while(cur_Cont._next != None and  dest > cur_Cont._next._dest):
            cur_Cont = cur_Cont._next

        if dest == cur_Cont._dest:
            if (cur_Cont._weight + weight) > 2000:
                self._size += 1
                cur_Cont._next = self.Container(owner, dest, \
                                                weight, cur_Cont._next)
                cur_Cont._next.add_pack(owner, dest, weight)
                return

            if (cur_Cont._weight + weight) <= 2000:
                cur_Cont.add_pack(owner, dest, weight)
                return

            if (cur_Cont._next._weight + weight) <= 2000:
                cur_Cont._next.add_pack(owner, dest, weight)
                return


        self._size += 1

        # Creates a new container with the given sepcifications.
        cur_Cont._next = self.Container(owner, dest, weight, cur_Cont._next)
        cur_Cont._next.add_pack(owner, dest, weight)

        return

    def traversePrint(self) :                      # Use for Printing Container
        cur_Cont = self._cont._first               # Modify to include details
        c_weight = cur_Cont._weight

        while cur_Cont != None: # of container or packages
            c_weight = cur_Cont._weight
            print(cur_Cont._dest, c_weight)
            cur_Cont.traversePrint()
            cur_Cont = cur_Cont._next


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Nested within the Shipyard

    class Container:
        def __init__(self, owner, dest, weight, next):
            self._owner = owner
            self._dest = dest
            self._first = None
            self._size = 0
            self._weight = 0
            self._next = next
            self._pack = self.Packages(None, None, None, None)

        def __len__(self):
            return self._size

        def isEmpty(self):
            return self._size == 0

        def add_pack(self, owner, dest, weight):
            # Add pack for container class which adds a package.

            if self.isEmpty() or weight < self._pack._first._weight:
                self._size += 1
                self._pack._first = self.Packages(owner, dest, \
                                                  weight, self._pack._first)
                self._weight += weight
                return

            cur_Pack = self._pack._first

            while(cur_Pack._next != None and weight > cur_Pack._next._weight):
                cur_Pack = cur_Pack._next

            if weight == cur_Pack._weight:
                self._size += 1
                cur_Pack._next = self.Packages(owner, dest, \
                                                weight, cur_Pack._next)
                self._weight += weight
                return

            self._size += 1
            cur_Pack._next = self.Packages(owner, dest, \
                                           weight, cur_Pack._next)
            self._weight += weight

            return

        def traversePrint(self):
            cur_Pack = self._pack._first               # Modify to include details

            p_weight = cur_Pack._weight

            while cur_Pack != None: # of container or packages
                p_weight = cur_Pack._weight
                if cur_Pack._dest == self._pack._dest:
                    print(cur_Pack._owner, cur_Pack._dest, p_weight, end = " ")
                    cur_Pack = cur_Pack._next
                else:
                    print(cur_Pack._owner, cur_Pack._dest, p_weight)
                    cur_Pack = cur_Pack._next    

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Nested within Container doesn't contain any methods

        class Packages:

            def __init__(self, owner, dest, weight, next):
                self._first = None
                self._size = 0
                self._owner = owner
                self._dest = dest
                self._weight = weight
                self._next = next

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Weight(Exception):
    pass

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
shipyard = Shipyard()

len(shipyard)

shipyard.add_pack("Lori", "Bristol", 300)
shipyard.add_pack("Mallory", "Bristol", 200)
shipyard.add_pack("Chung", "Alabama", 700)
shipyard.add_pack("Roger", "Alabama", 900)
shipyard.add_pack("Ali", "Giza", 45)
shipyard.add_pack("Soumick", "New Delhi", 600)
shipyard.add_pack("Mizuki", "Tokyo", 1900)
shipyard.add_pack("Tadashi", "Tokyo", 120)
shipyard.add_pack("Kanna", "Tokyo", 220)


shipyard.traversePrint()
```

This is what appears when program is ran:

```
Alabama 1600
Chung Alabama 700
Roger Alabama 900
Bristol 500
Mallory Bristol 200
Lori Bristol 300
Giza 45
Ali Giza 45
New Delhi 600
Soumick New Delhi 600
Tokyo 220
Kanna Tokyo 220
Tokyo 120 # THIS AND Tokyo 220 must be added into the same container
Tadashi Tokyo 120 # I don't know what I didn't include because
Tokyo 1900 # It seems to me that Alabama 700 and Alabama 900 were
Mizuki Tokyo 1900 # Adding Correctly.
```

PROBLEM EDIT: Packages that should be adding aren't adding up together and instead creates an entirely new container. I don't know what part of the code is messing up now T_T.

If there is a question please ask me in the comments below.

Thank you for reading.

Edit: I plan to use an additional add_pack(owner, dest, weight) in the Container section to hold the owner input/parameter and will be called in the Shipyard version of add_pack(owner,dest, weight)

Edit 2: SO I was able to fix the initial problem but now I have another problem/question. Yes, the school required us to use LinkedLists else we didn't get marks for it. Now my new problem is I don't know if I should update the weight of the container class in the **Shipyard method add_pack** or if I should update it when using **add_pack in the Container class.**

Edit 3.5: So I updated the code and now it clearly shows the two add_pack methods: One in the Shipyard class and one in the Container class. Sorry for bad edits and formatting. I'm just really frustrated at how I can't figure this thing out.

Edit 4: I've got both traversePrint on Container and Shipyard. Shipyard's traversePrint lists the Containers and Container's traversePrint lists the packages within the containers. I'm able to display the packages w/c leads me to believe they are being added correctly.

Edit 5: I've mostly figured out how to add containers, and packages into containers but some condition checking i.e. If weight of two things add over 2000 lbs else add into the same one <- this isn't working.

Comment: In your container creation method, can you just call the method again to create a second container if needed? If you're having trouble with this, can you show what is causing the issue or what part of the problem you're getting stuck on?

Comment: A couple of questions: what happens if the container is still not full but by adding a new package the total weight is more than 2000 lbs? And also: where is the owner information stored?

Comment: @toti08 it should create a new container under the same destination name. The owner information will be stored in the Packages class w/c I don't need here. I only wanted to know how to implement adding containers.
Conditions are: a. If containers will go over 2000 then the package is moved to a new container with the same destination name. b. If a package can fit into an existing container then it will be added inside without creating a newer one.

Comment: @UnsolvedCypher My problem with this is I can't seem to alter the code and make it so that say adding a package to the same container also adds the weight. i.e. like in the result section w/c shows Alabama 700 and Alabama 900 it should've resulted in Alabama 1600.  Tokyo 120 and Tokyo 1900 should've triggered a condition in which it would have only created the second Tokyo container because adding their weight will go over 2000 lbs which is what is required for this program.

Comment: Is there any reason for using a linked list here?  Why not stick with python's built in list type?

Comment: @xtofl I know it's a bit unintuitive but this was the specification for us.

Comment: I was going to ask the same question, using dictionaries with destination as keys and a list of container as value seems more intuitive to me, but if this is a school project it can make sense.

Comment: @toti08 I updated it because my initial problem was resolved and I'm now able to add new containers if weight passes over 2000 and add into existing containers if weight + container weight doesn't go over 2000

Comment: New problem however. I don't know whether to update the container weight inside the shipyard class or the container class. In the shipyard class I'm using the weight as a check if I should create a new container and in the container class I have no idea what to do or how to implement adding packages and updating the weight of the container and all that.

Comment: When updating your code, please post the updated code for us to help you.
In my eyes, your first output IS actually creating a new package when over 2000 lb Please post your updated code with the container add_pack, then I can help you to find out whether or not to have it inside the container or the shipyard. Although the shipyard sounds correct due to it being at the top of the hierarchy.

Comment: What do you mean by my first output creating a new package? w/c specific part of my code is it?

Comment: Nevermind, I just looked over your code and I see what you are talking about. Please post your updated code, then I can help you with your problem

Comment: Code is updated and includes all methods and classes that I've created. Shipyard has the first add_pack and Container has the other.

Comment: First of all you have two self._size inside your package class which is irrelevant. I do not believe the container class should have a owner, as the owner only pertains to the packages correct?  But anyway, inside of your container class you reference self._Packages which I don't believe exists, and also you are referencing cur_Cont inside your container class, which I don't believe your container class is able to access

Comment: word. Damn I missed a lot. My main problem though is I can't check if I'm creating my packages correctly. I was trying to do it in the traversePrint() method in the Shipyard class but should I be doing another traversePrint() inside the container class which then accesses the packages?

Comment: Yes you should create another traverse print for the packages inside the container. Both container and package are linked lists right? So it should be pretty similar to your container traverse print. Although I'm not sure if you are storing them correctly, try to figure out if your containers are actually adding packages, or if it's just adding one package and thats it then it modifies the weight but doesn't add another package. Not sure if I got my thought process across, I can try to clarify if that did not make sense

Comment: Yeah that is why I am trying to get traversePrint for the packages set-up so I can use it as a sort-of debug method that displays all linked packages within a container.

How do you suppose I fix my Container.add_pack method to properly store the packages? I thought it more or less took the same structure as the Shipyard.add_pack with just minor alterations. 

See my Shipyard add_pack creates linked containers and calls the Container add_pack. My Container add_pack then creates linked packages within a container object but I have no way of debugging currently. traversePrint might fix that.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21491677)

Comment: @Fireboy653 so I've once again updated the code with traversePrint in the Container class. While I can get the program to create another container in the instance the package weight + container weight goes over 2000 lbs, it still creates a new container even if the total weight doesn't exceed 2000 lbs I edited the result to show this problem

Answer (score 1):

Split the problem in happable chunks:

1. record the required shippables (as you currently do)
2. determine how many containers you need for each destination (probably `math.ceil(weight(dest) / 2000.0)` or something like that)

So your usage will become

```
shipyard.add_pack("X", "dest", 500)
shipyard.add_pack("X", "dest", 1500)
shipyard.add_pack("X", "dest", 2200)
...

containers = {
   dest: shipyard.containers_for(dest)
   for dest in shipyard.destinations()
}
```